# EpicEditor is not visible

Tags: javascript, epiceditor

I am trying to make `EpicEditor` to work and i have followed the instructions from the website:

HTML:

```
<div id="epiceditor"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var editor = new EpicEditor().load();
```

however when i load the page i get a blank page but with the following html:

```
<div id="epiceditor" style="height: 0px;"><iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="epiceditor-27565" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe></div>
```

The console shows no errors and all files have been loaded correctly. So what could the problem be?

Comment: have you tried typing some text ? try configuring some themes

Comment: Yeah i cannot type anything and it is still blank when using dark template

Comment: I have created a fiddle,adding jQuery, epiceditor.js and CSS, i am able to type text into it [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/vz3jdcrx/)

Comment: @karthick could another script be blocking me?

Comment: probably can u call the  `var editor = new EpicEditor().load();` from any button onClick event?

Comment: @karthick yeah i did but nothing changed

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I'm having this issue now, but only when I show epicEditor after hiding it on load. I.e. I radio buttons that toggle the visibility of the div that holds epicEditor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it works and you are not realize it.

Try like this. It works!

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/epiceditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="epiceditor"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = new EpicEditor().load();
</script>
```